# Fedora 27 - Laptop won't suspend when closing lid

Tags: linux, fedora, suspend, laptop, troubleshooting

I am facing this rather bizarre situation. After shutting down my laptop by pushing the power button for a few seconds and powering it on again the "suspend when lid is closed" option isn't working.

So when I close the lid, the laptop powers off. The strange thing is that when I open the lid the laptop powers on! This is strange because I don't push any power button whatsoever!

I checked my `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` file, but the following lines are uncommented

```
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
```

Any idea on what might be the issue?

I am pasting the entire `logind.conf` file, because it might be useful to locate the problem.

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See logind.conf(5) for details.

[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#UserTasksMax=12288
```

**UPDATE-1**

I upgraded my system to Fedora 27, but still the problem remains.
Any idea on how to solve it?

**UPDATE-2**

I tried @isapir answer, but it didn't work... More specifically

1. `$ swapon -s` 
   which gave

   `Filename               Type        Size    Used    Priority
   /dev/dm-2                               partition   7864316 0   -2`
2. Then I edited the `/etc/default/grub` file. On the entry about `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=` there was `"rd.lvm.lv=fedora/root rd.lvm.lv=fedora/swap rhgb quiet"` which I changed to `resume=/dev/dm-2`
3. To identify whether my system is `UEFI` or `legacy` I did `$ sudo efibootmgr`. The output was `EFI variables are not supported on this system.` which I guess means that I own a legacy system. So finally I did `grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2.cfg`

Any idea on how to proceed?

**UPDATE-3**

I also checked the journal typing

`sudo journalctl -b | grep "Feb 13" > journal.dat`

but I am not sure what am I looking for. You can find the output [here](https://pastebin.com/tb7vpT64)

Any idea on what's wrong?

Comment: IME, suspend is always fragile. What does the journal say about what's happening? Also F25 is no longer supported (or if it is, it's close to EOL). Have you tried upgrading to F27? Problems like this tend to be resolved with time, so older laptops tend to get "fixed", with newer models exhibiting problems.

Comment: [Fedora 25 end-of-life December 12, 2017](https://fedoramagazine.org/fedora-25-end-life/). I second the recommendation of doing an upgrade as the first step.

Comment: @Nick : Thanks a lot for your comment! Although F25 is no longer supported, I don't think an upgrade solves the problem, but I will try it! Thanks!

Comment: Do you see anything relevant in the journal?

Comment: @mattdm : What do you mean? Which journal? *I am new to Fedora - I used to be an ubuntu user for many years.

Comment: Issue `sudo journalctl` to see the journal. It logs everything that happens on systemd based systems. See `man journalctl` for how to use it.

Comment: @Mioriin Thanks for your comment! I did it! Check my updated answer!

Comment: @mattdm Thanks for your comment! I did what you suggested! Check my updated answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your laptop is trying to resume from the wrong partition.  That can be fixed in the `grub` by following the steps below:

As a superuser, run:

```
# swapon -s
```

That should show you which partition is used for Swap. On my machine, for example, it shows `/dev/dm-1`:

```
Filename        Type        Size     Used   Priority
/dev/dm-1       partition   8388604  0      -2
```

Next edit `/etc/default/grub` and find the line that starts with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=`.  It needs to have a value of `resume=<your-swap-device>`. In my example that is `resume=/dev/dm-1`.  If the resume entry is there, update it.  If not, add it.

Next you have to regenerate the grub.  On UEFI systems that would be:

```
# grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2-efi.cfg
```

On legacy systems that would be

```
# grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2.cfg
```

The next time that you open the lid your laptop should find the resume information and recover from suspend correctly.

[Reference](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1206936)

**EDIT** (from the OP)

An additional step is required :

Rebooting the laptop prior to closing the lid for the first time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! There was indeed an entry `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.lvm.lv=fedora/root rd.lvm.lv=fedora/swap rhgb quiet"` I will change it according to your answer! About the last step, how can I see whether I have `UEFI` or `legacy` system?

Comment: I did `[$ sudo efibootmgr` and the output was `EFI variables are not supported on this system.` so I guess I will have to run `# grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2.cfg`.

Comment: This didn't work. Laptop is still not suspending.

Comment: @Thanos did you figure this out? I had a similar issue, and after adding the `resume=` bit to my grub config, I had to run `dracut --regerate-all --force` to make it work /shrug